# Getting constant delay between TCP Socket data send C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a Client-Server application in C# 2010.
In TCP Socket i setup Nodelay = True, and SendBufferSize = 0 for all the connected socket (client-Server) in my application.

I am tracing every incoming-outgoing packets and writing that in logfile using streamwriter, which has autoflush property set true.

I noticed 1 thing that sometimes there is a constant delay (15-16ms) between 2 data packets while sending data.
after few continuous sending this delay appears again.

Why this delay? and how can i avoid it....

See the images...

http://s4.postimg.org/uoly38shp/Trace_1.png
http://s14.postimg.org/m4ab7oght/Trace_2.png

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.aspx) to track your performance 15ms is about the provided resolution. Try using [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) which is more reliable.

Comment: For writing trace, I am just writing time to get the idea when the packet actually received from the client sockets. I am looking for GAP of (14-16ms) between two packet process event in my server.

Comment: That was my point, the source of your time is probably causing what only appears to be 15ms delays. If you use a more reliable time source the 15ms delay will probably no longer be there.

Comment: You mean for logging this packet data, i should use StopWatch in "StreamWriter.WriteLine" instead of datetime???

Comment: That's what I was suggesting. It may turn out I'm wrong, is only a best guess.

Comment: @Bill - Great hear. You can still accept the answer if this helped.